# can chisel translates firrtl to verilog in parallel/multi cpu?

Tags: parallel-processing, chisel

I designed in chisel a mesh-array of registers, say 32x32 Bytes of D-flipflop, to take a try to implement such parrallel hardware arch in chisel. The firrtl file is like 100k lines, looks like a netlist. Then the time costed by the translation from firrtl to verilog is like many hours. During this period of time the processing is just arranged on a single CPU.
Could you enlight me how to make it running parallel on CPUs?

The key codes:

```
val reg_vec = (0 to 31).map(i=>
                (0 to 31).map(j=>
                  Module(new MyNodeOfReg(8))
  )
)
```

The scala compiler and code runner version 2.11.8

I made a run batch like this, do ./run then wait for ./target/Bench.v:

```
mkdir target
cp /opt/eda_tool/RISCV/top.cpp target
scalac -d target -cp $CP Top.scala Test.scala
scala  -cp $CP org.scalatest.run Test
```

in which scalac/scala is auto-generated after scala installation
in which My Test.scala is :

```
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._
import chisel3.testers._
import org.scalatest._
import org.scalacheck._
import org.scalatest.prop._
import scala.sys.process._

class Bench() extends BasicTester {
  val dut = Module(new Top())
  val t = Reg(UInt(width=32),init=0.U)
  t := t+1.U

  when(t<=1.U) {
  }.elsewhen(t===100.U) {
    stop()
  }
}

class Test extends PropSpec with PropertyChecks {

  property("elaborate") {
    Driver.elaborate (() => { new Top() })
  }

  property("should return the correct result") {
    TesterDriver.execute(() => { new Bench() })
  }

}
```

The Top.scala is:

```scala
import chisel3._
import chisel3.util._

object ce_pm{
  val div = 4
  val e = 1   
  val ec= 1   
  val p = 10 // 16/div        
  val s = p*p       
  val w = s*e       

  val ext = 64      
  val extw= ext*e   

  val irp = 20 // 40/div  // InREG parameter
  val irn = irp*irp // InREG reg number
}

class Mux4(n: Int) extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val i = Input(Vec(4,UInt(n.W)))
    val s = Input(UInt(2.W))
    val o = Output(UInt(n.W))
  })
  val mux00 = Wire(UInt(n.W))
  val mux01 = Wire(UInt(n.W))
  mux00 := Mux(io.s(0)===1.U,io.i(1),io.i(0))
  mux01 := Mux(io.s(0)===1.U,io.i(3),io.i(2))
  io.o  := Mux(io.s(1)===1.U,mux01,mux00)
}

class CEIO_TwoD_Torus extends Bundle {
  val n = Input(UInt(ce_pm.e.W))
  val s = Input(UInt(ce_pm.e.W))
  val w = Input(UInt(ce_pm.e.W))
  val e = Input(UInt(ce_pm.e.W))
}

class TwoD_TorusReg extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val i = new CEIO_TwoD_Torus()
    val o = new CEIO_TwoD_Torus().flip
    val d = Input(UInt(ce_pm.e.W)) 
    val c = Input(Vec(4,UInt(1.W)))
  })
  val r = Reg(UInt(ce_pm.e.W),init=0.U)
  val u_mux4 = Module(new Mux4(ce_pm.e))
  u_mux4.io.i(0) := io.i.e
  u_mux4.io.i(1) := io.i.s
  u_mux4.io.i(2) := io.i.w
  u_mux4.io.i(3) := io.i.n
  u_mux4.io.s    := Cat(io.c(2),io.c(1))
  when (io.c(0) === 1.U) {
    when (io.c(3) === 0.U) {
      r := u_mux4.io.o
    } .otherwise {
      r := io.d
    }
  } 
  io.o.e := r
  io.o.s := r
  io.o.w := r
  io.o.n := r
}

class Top extends Module {
  val io = IO(new Bundle{
    val i = Input (UInt(ce_pm.extw.W))
    val o = Output(Vec(ce_pm.p,Vec(ce_pm.p,UInt(ce_pm.e.W))))
    val c = Input (UInt(7.W))
  })
  val n  = ce_pm.irp
  val r_vec = (0 to n-1).map ( i=>
                (0 to n-1).map ( j=>
                  Module(new TwoD_TorusReg)
                )
              )
  for (i <- 0 to n-1) {
    for (j <- 0 to n-1) {
      r_vec(i)(j).io.c(0) := io.c(1)
      r_vec(i)(j).io.c(3) := io.c(0)
      r_vec(i)(j).io.c(2) := io.c(2)
      r_vec(i)(j).io.c(1) := io.c(3)
    }
  }
  // out
  val m = ce_pm.p
  for (i <- 0 to m-1) {
    for (j <- 0 to m-1) {
      io.o(i)(j) := r_vec(i)(j).io.o.e
    }
  }
  //2-D-Torus interconnection
  for (i <- 1 to n-1) {
    for (j <- 1 to n-1) {
      r_vec(i)(j).io.i.w := r_vec(i)(j-1).io.o.e
      r_vec(i)(j).io.i.n := r_vec(i-1)(j).io.o.s
    }
  }
  for (i <- 0 to n-2) {
    for (j <- 0 to n-2) {
      r_vec(i)(j).io.i.e := r_vec(i)(j+1).io.o.w
      r_vec(i)(j).io.i.s := r_vec(i+1)(j).io.o.n
    }
  }
  for (i <- 0 to n-1) {
    r_vec(i)(0).io.i.w := r_vec(i)(n-1).io.o.e
    r_vec(0)(i).io.i.n := r_vec(n-1)(i).io.o.s
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a very gnarly performance bug so if you could provide more information about your design that would be very helpful (or code would be even better). You can also try using the command-line option `-ll info` to provide the runtime of each of the Firrtl passes.

[rocket-chip](https://github.com/freechipsproject/rocket-chip)-based projects frequently generate hundreds of thousands to millions of lines of firrtl which are usually compiled on the order of seconds to minutes. For this reason we have not yet felt the need to parallelize the code.

EDIT:
Thank you for adding the code!

I'm struggling to reproduce the performance problems you're seeing. With `irp = 32`, compilation from Firrtl to Verilog is taking about 4 seconds; total compilation including Chisel is taking about 8 seconds. Should I be changing other parameters as well? I am compiling with:

```scala
object Main extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new Top)
}
```

Can you share a little bit more about how you're building the Module?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it's helpful and I will keep following to provide more information into the question discription. Yes the firrtl is OK, the performance issue happens after the firrtl is generated.

Comment: I tried `-ll info` as the code runner's parameter but it won't be recognized.

Comment: I asked in my edit above as well, but can you share a little bit more about how you're building the design? Are you using the chisel-testers or just generating Verilog?

Comment: I think the performance problem is in on of the gcc compilations.  That's where I see most of the time begin spent

Comment: @jkoenig Sure. I am adding the whole dir. I think you bring me closer to the source of my problem.

Comment: @jkoenig https://github.com/freechipsproject/chisel3/issues/640 is a copy of this question. Mr. "chick" may have reproduced it. I think you are using the default sbt/chisel project, while short of knowlege, I am in trouble to understand and use it.

Answer (score 0):

@jkoenig by your suggestion, I found something new.

First, as I had got the Bench.fir, so I direct run firrtl

> firrtl -i Bench.fir -o my.v -X verilog

Then the verilog generated in seconds, as fast as you said. Wow~

Second, then I add this code in Top.scala

```
package mytest
object GenVlgTop extends App {
  chisel3.Driver.execute(args, () => new Top)
}
```

update run

```
scalac -d target -cp $CP Top.scala 
scala  -cp $CP mytest.GenVlgTop
```

Then the time ./run to generate firrtl is very long as it was as before

```
[info] [0.002] Elaborating design...
[info] [1.290] Done elaborating.
```

the log stops and waits here while firrtl is not generated.

So far a solution is like this:

```
1. do the original ./run, when it's waiting, 
2. C-c to interrupt the processing
3. firrtl the generated *.fir
```